# Win32 Edit control in 3ds MAX plugin

Tags: winapi, 3dsmax

I am writing a plugin for 3ds MAX (2013/2014). In my plugin I have a **Modeless** dialog and a Win32 **Edit Control**. After showing the dialog when i try to edit the text in the edit control, the text is not updating. The edit caret is in the text box.

I tried spy++ and it shows that all the keyboard events **WM_KEYDOWN**, **WM_CHAR** and **WM_KEYUP** is processed by the edit control.

Actually When I press a key in the edit control, key board shortcuts of 3ds MAX is activated.

If I change the dialog type to **Modal**, the edit control works perfectly. The edit control provided by 3ds MAX (**ICustEdit**) works fine in the Modeless dialog.

My Edit control, is a customized one (it supports multiple lines and it will re-size its height according to the number of lines), so I cannot directly use the ICustEdit.

I tried to change the size and position of a ICustEdit using **SetWindowPos**, but it was not working(the control went invisible :) ).

So to conclude I have two questions,

1. Why my Win32 Edit control is not working?
2. Is there a way to sub class the ICustEdit and change its size and position from code just like a normal Edit Control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3dsmax uses what it calls **accelerators**. These are application wide low level keyboard overrides, used for general hotkey support. As a result, any custom control must disable these overrides whenever it receives focus.

You should call `DisableAccelerators()` defined in `custcont.h`, whenever your custom control gets focus (on `WM_GOTFOCUS` message).

this is why the `ICustEdit` does work, it calls this internally.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the 3DS MAX Keyboard Accelerators. After you told me about the accelerators I searched about in the 3DS MAX documentation. [Keyboard Accelerators and Dialog Messages](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/index.html?url=files/GUID-600B5841-6AFD-44B5-9E81-662AE02934E4.htm,topicNumber=d30e39303) is the link to official documentation.